# How to setup Spring Data Solr with EmbeddedSolrServer and multicore support?

Tags: spring-data-solr

I'm using Spring Data Solr to implement the search module in my project. To enable multicore support, I simply instantiate a *HttpSolrServer* and then declare a java-based Spring configuration class with `@EnableSolrRepositores(multicoreSupport=true)`. Everything works perfectly, until when I try to write integration test for Solr related codes and schema.

I want to use *EmbeddedSolrServer* for testing so that the tests can run without depending on an external Solr server, but I can't find a way to configure correctly. Please advise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can at this time not be done directly due to [DATASOLR-203](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATASOLR-203).

Once the issue mentioned above is resolved you can do it as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSolrRepositories(multicoreSupport = true)
static class SolrConfiguration {

  @Bean
  SolrServer solrServer() throws FileNotFoundException {

    String solrHome = ResourceUtils.getURL("classpath:your/path/here").getPath();
    CoreContainer container = CoreContainer.createAndLoad(solrHome, new File(solrHome + "/solr.xml"));

    return new EmbeddedSolrServer(container, null);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'll give 1.2.5 a try once it is out.

Comment: @NikhilSahu EmbeddedSolrServer is not depracated i just tested it with solr-core-5.4.1

Comment: spring-data-solr uses solrj4. Explicitly mentioning later versions of solrj dependency will show SolrServer as deprecated and now inherits from SolrClient. All functions have been moved to SolrClient.

Comment: SD-Solr 2.0.0.M1 moved to Solr 5. `EmbeddedSolrServer` extends `SolrClient` and can be created via the [`EmbeddedSolrServerFactory`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-solr/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/solr/server/support/EmbeddedSolrServerFactory.java)